# Fix Unsupported Browser

Tags: swiftui, webkit

I am having a problem where if I navigate to somewhere like Gmail or google docs, then I am getting a message like "Gmail may not work well with this browser, please upgrade to a supported browser" and same thing with Youtube.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavigationState
    @Binding var proxy: GeometryProxy
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView  {
        return UIView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        guard let webView = navigationState.selectedWebView else {
            return
        }
        if webView != uiView.subviews.first {
            uiView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
            
            webView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: proxy.size)
            uiView.addSubview(webView)
            
        }
    }

}

class NavigationState : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentURL : URL?
    @Published var webViews : [WKWebView] = []
    @Published var selectedWebView : WKWebView?
    var buttonLongPressPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var nextURL: URL?
    
    @discardableResult func createNewWebView(withRequest request: URLRequest) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
        
        let wv = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
        webViews.append(wv)
        selectedWebView = wv
        wv.load(request)
        return wv
    }

    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        currentURL = webView.url
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            nextURL = url
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "buttonLongPress" {
            print("Pressed long")
        }
    }


}

extension NavigationState : WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if webView == selectedWebView {
            self.currentURL = webView.url
        }
    }
    
    func websiteName(from urlString: String) -> String? {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            if let host = url.host {
                let components = host.components(separatedBy: ".")
                if components.count >= 2 {
                    return components[components.count - 2] // Assuming that the website name is the second-to-last component
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func websiteImage(from urlString: String) -> String? {
        if urlString.hasSuffix("/favicon.ico") {
            return urlString
        } else {
            return urlString + "/favicon.ico"
        }
    }
    
    func getFavicon(from urlString: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            if let doc = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                if let range = doc.range(of: "(?<=<link rel=\"icon\" href=\")[^\"]+", options: .regularExpression) {
                    let favicon = String(doc[range])
                    completion(favicon)
                } else if let range = doc.range(of: "(?<=<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\")[^\"]+", options: .regularExpression) {
                    let favicon = String(doc[range])
                    completion(favicon)
                } else {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I tried using a fake agent but that still isn't working. I feel it is something to do with the `NavigationState`